# Change font size in arabtex package

Tags: fonts, fontsize, languages, arabic

I need to write some words in Arabic in a LaTeX file. I'm currently using `arabtex` package to do that as following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
 \begin{document}
 \RL{f.s.hY AltrA_t} % Arabic word
 \end{document}
```

The problem is that the size of the font used in `arabtex` style is large and this affects the document layout which changes in undesirable way. I searched for the file `arabtex.sty` in my PC's drives but it seems there is no such file on my PC. I just need to be able to change the font size of words written in `arabtex` style.

Comment: I don't see any large font when running the example.

Comment: If the Arabic words appear within English text and if the document is single line space , the problem must be obvious. the layout of the paper I am writing now is changed 100% and I have got untidy appearance

Comment: If I write `A \RL{f.s.hY AltrA_t} B`, the Arabic text is as high as the Latin letters.

Comment: If you highlight the text in the pdf resulted file (using mouse). you can see the difference in high between latin letters and the Arabic words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using what the `arabtex` names "small" version, you get reduced size that's comparable to the size of Latin characters:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex,lipsum}

%%% from Uxnsh.fd
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{xnsh}{}%

\DeclareFontShape{U}{xnsh}{m}{n}{%                                   
   <-6> sfixed * [6.0] xnsh14
      <6-10> s * [1.20] xnsh14
         <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88> s * [1.20] xnsh14
         }{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{xnsh}{bx}{n}{%
   <-6> sfixed * [6.0] xnsh14bf
   <6-10> s * [1.20] xnsh14bf
   <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88> s * [1.20] xnsh14bf
}{}
%%% end of added code


\begin{document}


\lipsum*[2]
\RL{f.s.hY AltrA_t} % Arabic word
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: but there's still an uneven line skip between the first line with arabic and the line above it.  i think that the arabic implementation has been designed to accommodate the maximum diacritization, even though it isn't used in the example text.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way for me to change font size (using pdflatex book class; \usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{arabtex}\usepackage{utf8} with \setcode{utf8} in document part) was this: "some english text \<\tiny السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته> some english text" using one's desired font size as per the arabtex manual (http://baobab.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/arabtex/doc/arabdoc.pdf). I found \RL{} generates an error when used in endnotes (enotez package, hyperref backref=true) but works fine in bottom-of-page footnotes and main text. I used \smash{} to reduce vertical space in the endnote line, but not sure it really does much.

I also used \spreadtrue/\spreadfalse before and after \smash{} to better space the arabic text. I had to use \tiny in my endnotes to achieve proper vertical linespacing; it prints out quite readable. MWE's never seem to replicate my book even if I copy-paste the entire preamble, however, so below is an example endnote. Line breaking seems to be manually required with arabtex but it worked out for me without having to deal with it. Hope this helps. A very general thanks to all the StackExchange Latex experts who helped me solve a myriad of nerve-wrecking---Yes, I mean wrecking---problems over the last couple months.

[image]